# discord.py Not able to fetch messages

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

In discord.py, I have a @tasks.loop which runs every 10 seconds. It fetches a message by `channel.fetch_message(message-id)` and edits it from `hi` to `hello`. After another 10 seconds, it changes the message back to `hi`. It works as normal at first. However, when the bot auto restarts, it is unable to fetch the message. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

`commands.Bot` doesn't have the `fetch_message` attribute only `abc.Messageable` have. To fetch a message, first you need to get the channel where is the message sent, and then fetch it.

```py
# Getting the channel
channel = bot.get_channel(id_here)
# if you want a faster way:
channel = Guild.get_channel(id_here)

# Getting the message
message = await channel.fetch_message(id_here)
```

Comment: Oh, I did do that, I just misspelt it in the question. I have edited the question to correct my mistake.